# How to get number of value based on type?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database:

```
pID    |type| City     |   
------------------
Z0D12  | Z  | Amsterdam
XOD12  | X  | Paris
YOD12  | Y  | Madrid
GOD12  | G  | Amsterdam
GOD12  | G  | Amsterdam
```

I have a composite key with a date row so the pID can be a duplicate

I want to display the amount of times a city occurs per type:

```
City       |type    | amountoftimes |   
------------------
Amsterdam  | Z      | 1
Amsterdam  | G      | 2
Paris      | X      | 1
Madrid     | Y      | 1
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be something like:

```
select citiTable.city, citiTable.type, count(*) as amountOfTimes
from citiTable
group by citiTable.city, citiTable.type
```

The documentation on how to use count can be found [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/count.php)

Comment: You don't need to prefix each column with the table name when the query includes a single table.